# Is there a possibility for electricity to go through a computer screen?

Tags: science-fiction, artificial-intelligence, computers, electricity, nanotechnology

The picture below shows the main idea to my question.  That is manipulated electricity makes an attempt to go through a monitor screen.  The AI must have sent something tiny enough, like electrons or something conductive, into the computer screen. Before sending in the conductors, it made tiny holes through the screen. The AI temporarily implanted very tiny conductors into the CRT screen, via nanotechnology. The electricity travels through the air, in order to go through the screen where there are tiny conductors implanted. Another thing is the AI controls the amount of power of the electricity. Once the electricity goes into the screen, the power increases until it completely penetrates through the screen.

**Clarification:**

**Could this be a possibility for electricity to go through a CRT screen by building tiny conductors into the screen?**

**How about a possibility for electricity to go through a LCD screen and LED screen by building tiny conductors into both computer screens?**

**Bonus: If the first way("temporary tiny conductors built into computer screen") is a "possibility", how would the second way("creates a higher voltage within the screen") be a "possibility"?**

[image]

Comment: SIde notes: This is another sci-fi idea, so I get that it's not in the real world(yet). I am talking about the "physical" electricity, the one that can make you shocked when touched(to explain what I mean by "electricity").

Comment: That already happens naturally, you don't need an AI for that. Take a look at how CRTs work: https://electronics.howstuffworks.com/tv3.htm

Comment: @AnonymousInquirer "physical electricity" isn't a generally recognized term amongst physicists and electrical engineers. I think you're talking about the static shock you could receive from old monitors. If that's the case then the idea that the shock is happening through the screen is a flawed one.

Comment: Old CRT (cathode ray tubes) worked by bombarding the inside of the screen with high-energy electrons (10,000V+). The best you could get was spraying it with window clearner and then touching it, which would ignite the alcohol in the cleaner. Embedding conductors would make the screen a little dangerous to touch, but it would also destroy the screen (everything would be blurry).  There's also not enough current to hurt a person (not at the screen).  IF they were grounded (carpet, shoes, chairs... almost nothing is conductive), you could arc to the person, but it would only startle them.

Comment: BTW, voltage causes sparks.  Current kills.  You can hold fluorescent bulbs in your hands standing near a high voltage arc generator and the bulbs will glow and you won't feel a thing.  On the other hand, if you're dumb enough to grab both posts on a 12V car battery there will be no spark, but it can kill you.  The higher the voltage, the more likely the current will race across your skin rather than penetrating to your heart.  The higher the current the less voltage matters (quite quickly, too).

Answer (score 2):

Not really, unless the ai controls the manufacturing of all of the parts. An LED display is essentially a couple of sheets of glass with interesting impurities. The amount of electricity you describe would fry the led display,  and drilling holes in it even with nanotechnology would leave the screen surface obviously disfigured (frosted).

Comment: If the voltage is weak, electric current can't go through the computer screen.  If the voltage is just right, electric current can go through.  If the voltage is too much, electric current would definitely break the computer screen.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of electric current you would need to do that would fry your electric jumper before anything else so ... sadly no, no chance .